# How to find declaration of "flutter dot" constants contained in build.gradle?

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, android-min-sdk

When creating a new flutter project (these days, 2023), it uses external constants for the min, target, and compile SDKs like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blah"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Where can I find where these "flutter." constants are stored/declared?  I tried right click, "go to declaration" but it doesn't work.  The IDE (Android Studio) is treating it as if it were just plain text.

Comment: Do you have a `local.properties` file? I've seen some of these variables there.